# Showing multiple PowerPoint presentations in selected order

Tags: powerpoint, presentation

Has anyone heard about an application in which I could e.g. drag'n'drop ppt files in some order, and then play them in the loop?

I don't want to insert slides/file in PowerPoint, I have a lot of presentations and I want to display each day a different set of ppt files. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you could program it fairly simple.
Simply use Powerpoint interop, start the presentation and when it finished,, play the next one.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get an idea..?